# Selenium and Facebook Post Button: How to click facebook post button in java using selenium?

Tags: java, facebook, selenium

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/sachin.aryal");
driver.findElement(By.name("xhpc_message_text")).sendKeys("Testing Java and Selenium");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='u_0_1a']/div/div[6]/div/ul/li[2]/button")).click();
```

The last line of the code is not working. How do I set the XPath of the Post button on facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you already marked your own answer but it's not the proper way to do this. There are ways built into Selenium to do waits, e.g. wait for an element to be clickable. This method is the proper and more efficient way to do this.

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/sachin-aryal/");
driver.findElement(By.name("xhpc_message_text")).sendKeys("Testing Java and Selenium");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button/span[.=\"Post\"]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed it works when you first scroll into view the button, try adding before the click on post the:

```
     ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,259)","");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code .. it must work for you..

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;



public class Facebook_login {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String user_name = "facebook_user_name";
        String pwd = "facebook_password";
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys(user_name);
        driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys(pwd);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'Log In')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);                
        System.out.println("logged in successfully");
        WebElement notification = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@action,'cancel')]"));
        if(notification.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("Notification is present");
            notification.click();
        }
        WebElement status =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='xhpc_message']"));
        status.sendKeys("Hello");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Post']"))).click();


    }
}
```