# Why does SeleniumDriver/Java need to scroll down to allow me to post on facebook?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was/am trying to make Selenium Driver post a Facebook Post normally using the Firefox Driver but wasn't/ain't able to do it normally: for some reason I have to make the browser scroll down before I click the "post" button otherwise I get an error.

Here is my code:

**Code-listing 1: Main.java**

```
package main;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\PortableApps\\Webdrivers\\geckodriver.exe");

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions()
                  .addPreference("browser.startup.page", 1)
                  .addPreference("permissions.default.desktop-notification", 1)
                  .addPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-US")
                  .addPreference("browser.startup.homepage", "https://www.google.co.uk");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        driver.findElement(By.className("inputtext")).sendKeys("ghostbrain@hotmail.fr");
        driver.findElements(By.className("inputtext")).get(1).sendKeys("Xrt4LV512");
        driver.findElement(By.className("inputtext")).submit();
        

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        WebElement postBox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("feedx_sprouts_container")));
        postBox.click();
        
        postBox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(By.id("feedx_sprouts_container"), By.className("notranslate")));
        postBox.sendKeys("Hello Post!");
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);//Necessary because of the way facebook works
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        
        WebElement postButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#feedx_sprouts_container button[type=submit]")));
        postButton.click();
        
    }
}
```

if I run that code I get an error from facebook stating:

> Your request couldn't be processed
>
> There was a problem with this request. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can.

[image: visual representation of the facebook request couldn't be processed]

to solve this I had to use a solution from [Selenium and Facebook Post Button: How to click facebook post button in java using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053535/selenium-and-facebook-post-button-how-to-click-facebook-post-button-in-java-usi). That is I had to make the browser scroll down using the follwing code after the Thread.sleep() try/catch.

**Code-listing 2: Extra**

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,259)","");
```

It works, but it isn't normal and I am afraid I will hit another wall with facebook later if I don't know the reasons behind this bug.

Comment: I would check the network logs in the browser.  It could be possible that Facebook doesn't want scripts to execute on it's pages so it stops potential scripts.  One way they might do it is via checking if a user has scrolled.

Comment: Why isn't it normal? if you try to post on facebook manually can you do it without scrolling to make the post button visible?

Comment: @Guy not exactly. It actually depends on the browser's window dimension. My screen resolution is 1920x1080. So if I maximize the browser window, I won't need to scroll to make the post button visible.

Comment: @PaikuHan The point is that if the button is not visible you can't click it, t's not impotent what is the reason it's not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code, use `Actions` and change some locator:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
Actions act = new Actions(driver);

WebElement postBox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("xhpc_message")));
act.moveToElement(postBox).click().build().perform();

WebElement postBox2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("._1mf._1mj")));
act.moveToElement(postBox2).click().sendKeys("Hello Post").build().perform();

WebElement postButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#feedx_sprouts_container button[type=submit]")));
postButton.click();
```

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Comment: Tried you code. it solves the issue but doesn't tell me why. And more importantly how do I know when to use Actions and when it's not necessary to use them.

Comment: @PaikuHan Glad it worked, sometimes we can't click the element by `.click()` method, instead you can use click by `Actions` class, maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295483/selenium-webdriver-click-vs-action-click-whats-the-difference/23328650#23328650) can will give a bit information. By the way if you want, please mark the answer as accept, feel free :)

Comment: I was waiting for your comment above before I mark it as the answer.